# Laravel - Issue in getting session value

Tags: php, laravel

I have used the below code.
For saving session -
Session::put('seval', $val);

For fetching data from session-

```
{{ session()->get('seval') }}
```

This is what I am using but seems the issue is somewhere else. Is there any option to enable /disable session in configuration files?
session is working on same page but when I click on some button that redirects to next page, session value disappears. Can anyone help me to find out where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for this is...

```
    Session::set('variableName', $value);
```

For Laravel 5.4 and later, the correct method to use is put.

```
    Session::put('variableName', $value);
```

To get the variable, you'd use...

```
    Session::get('variableName');
```

Comment: session() is a helper

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this as well. but its not working. I need to display this session value in blade file.

Comment: @Prerna This should work,can you just try before that session value is set or not using Session::has('seval')